# Redirect based on only part of referring URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'm working with a client who has a site with many subdomains representing different areas covered in his locksmith business. He picks up a lot of traffic from directory websites, and wants to use his domain only as the link on these websites. When someone clicks it, he wants them to be redirected based on a keyword in the referring URL.

For example, a referring Yell URL could be

```
yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?keywords=locksmith&location=Watford%2C+Hertfordshire&scrambleSeed=1311994593
```

Client wants htaccess or something similar to pick out the keyword **'Watford'** from that URL, and redirect to **watford.hisbusiness.com** accordingly.

This isn't something I've done before and I'm baffled. Research found no clues.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `HTTP_REFERER` to grab information from the referring URL.

```bsh
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} yell\.com/.*\?.*\&location\=(\w+)\%2C\+(\w+)
RewriteRule ^$ http://${lower:%1}.hisbusiness.com/ [R=302,L]
```

The `${lower:$1}` is used to make *Watford* lowercase. In order for this to work, you'll need to add the following to your `httpd.conf` or virtual host configuration file:

```bsh
RewriteMap lower int:tolower
```

**Note:** The rule in place above is designed for the domain root (`hisbusiness.com`) only - that is to say that a request to `hisbusiness.com/something` won't trigger the redirect. If you'd like it to check for the URI as well, use the following rule instead:

```bsh
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://${lower:%1}.hisbusiness.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

To make the redirect permanent and cached by browsers/search-engines, change `302` to `301`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Header` on PHP using your required conditions:

```
if(condition 1){
header("Location: http://mywebsite1.com");
}

if(condition 2){
header("Location: http://mywebsite2.com");
}

else{
header("Location: http://mywebsite3.com");
}
```

You can use `[stristr][1]` on the if condition.